# Unable to return child values when parsing xml using etree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an xml file that looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<FullReport
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <firm>1426</firm>
    <reportDate>07FEB2020_18:00:00.000000</reportDate>
    <rooms>
        <room>
            <roomID>PCHAT-0x0000000000000637</roomID>
            <roomTitle>FX - WBB - CTON</roomTitle>
            <description>global chat</description>
            <creationDate></creationDate>
            <removalDate></removalDate>
            <lastActivityDate>02/07/2020 12:26:24</lastActivityDate>
            <status>Active</status>
            <membership>Bilateral</membership>
            <isAnonymous>false</isAnonymous>
            <hasActiveAdmins>true</hasActiveAdmins>
            <activeUserCount>17</activeUserCount>
            <distinctFirmsInRoom>2</distinctFirmsInRoom>
            <isInternalOnly>false</isInternalOnly>
            <isIncognitoForum>false</isIncognitoForum>
        </room>
        <users>
            <uuid>6820</uuid>
            <bbgEmail>SJONES@Bloomberg.net</bbgEmail>
            <fullName>SEAN JONES</fullName>
            <firmName>BANK OF TEST</firmName>
            <firmNumber>1400</firmNumber>
            <accountNumber>51067</accountNumber>
            <accountName>BANK OF TEST</accountName>
            <inviteDate>01/07/2013 22:00:39</inviteDate>
            <isDeleted>false</isDeleted>
            <isAdmin>false</isAdmin>
            <isCreator>false</isCreator>
            <roomAlias>CTON</roomAlias>
            <corpEmail>sean.jones@botest.com</corpEmail>
            <city>LONDON</city>
        </users>
        <users>
            <uuid>6820</uuid>
            <bbgEmail>SSMITH@Bloomberg.net</bbgEmail>
            <fullName>SEAN SMITH</fullName>
            <firmName>BANK OF TEST</firmName>
            <firmNumber>1400</firmNumber>
            <accountNumber>51067</accountNumber>
            <accountName>BANK OF TEST</accountName>
            <inviteDate>01/07/2013 22:00:39</inviteDate>
            <isDeleted>false</isDeleted>
            <isAdmin>false</isAdmin>
            <isCreator>false</isCreator>
            <roomAlias>CTON</roomAlias>
            <corpEmail>sean.smith@botest.com</corpEmail>
            <city>LONDON</city>
        </users>
</FullReport>
</FullReport>
```

I am parsing the data using the following code:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et

tree = et.parse('test.xml')
print (tree.getroot())
root = tree.getroot()
print ("tag=%s, attrib=%s" % (root.tag, root.attrib))

for child in root:
        print (child.tag, child.attrib)
        if child.tag == "room":
            for step_child in child:
                print (step_child.tag)

# get the information via the children!
print ("-" * 40)
print ("Iterating using a getchildren()")
print ("-" * 40)
rooms = root.getchildren()
for room in rooms:
    room_children = room.getchildren()
    for room_child in room_children:
        print ("%s=%s" % (room_child.tag, room_child.text))
```

When I print the room_child.tag and room_child.text I don't see the values? Quite new to this so I'm not sure what I am missing?

Results returned are:

[image]

My eventual aim is to iterate over each value and convert to CSV but i'm stuck accessing the values and not sure why no data is returning. I would like the eventual csv to look similar to with a row for each user in the csv

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, the formatting of the code you shared looks broken.

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: I'd like to see the data for each "Room" along with the "Users" attached to each room. I want to flatten this down to a csv.

Comment: Reproducible code now added. So I was expecting the attributes for each "room" along with their values and the attributes/values for each "user" attached to the room to be printed.

Comment: Your xml is invalid; can you edit and fix it?

Comment: Xml has been fixed.

Comment: Now can you edit the question and provide a sample of your desired output? It's still not clear.

Comment: Sample of desired output added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210039/discussion-between-jack-fleeting-and-sql-pete-belfast).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `for child in root:` then this loop iterates **only**
over direct descendants of *FullReport*, in your case: *firm*,
*reportDate* and *rooms*, so it has no chance to get at *room*, which is
located one step lower.

From your code (the first loop) I see that you are actually interested
in direct descendants of *FullReport/rooms/room*.

To print their tag names and text content, you can run e.g.:

```
for child in root.iter('room'):
    for step_child in child:
        print(f'{step_child.tag:20} {step_child.text}')
```

For your sample input, the result is:

```
roomID               PCHAT-0x0000000000000637
roomTitle            FX - WBB - CTON
description          global chat
creationDate         None
removalDate          None
lastActivityDate     02/07/2020 12:26:24
status               Active
membership           Bilateral
isAnonymous          false
hasActiveAdmins      true
activeUserCount      17
distinctFirmsInRoom  2
isInternalOnly       false
isIncognitoForum     false
```

And as far as your final task is concerned, you can run:

```
rows = []
for child in root.iter('rooms'):
    roomId, roomTitle = 'id', 'ttl'
    for it in child:
        if it.tag == 'room':
            roomId = it.findtext('roomID')
            roomTitle = it.findtext('roomTitle')
        elif it.tag == 'users':
            rows.append([roomId, roomTitle, it.findtext('uuid'), it.findtext('bbgEmail'),
                it.findtext('fullName'), it.findtext('firmName')])
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['roomId', 'roomTitle', 'uuid', 'bbgEmail',
    'fullName', 'firmName'])
```

The code above is based on assumption that *room* element occurs first
and after them there are *users* elements.

And add code concerning any additional columns not shown in your post.